# Is there a single call method of splitting a list (iterable) into two parts?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a built-in or Pythonic way to do this? Or maybe my question should be: Is there a better way to write the dictionary comprehension example at the end of this question?

```
def split_list(list, index):
    return list[:index], list[index:]
```

I find myself needing to do this in list comprehensions where I get lists from some generator and want to split the lists into two pieces. For example, a text file like the following:

```
txt_file = """key1 value value value value
key2 value value value value
"""
import io
{k:v
 for line in io.StringIO(txt_file)
 for items in (line.strip().split(),)
 for k, v in ((items[0], items[1:]),)}
```

Output:

```
{'key1': ['value', 'value', 'value', 'value'],
 'key2': ['value', 'value', 'value', 'value']}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only comment I'd make is that there's no real reason for your last `for` in that comprehension.

```
{items[0]:items[1:]
 for line in io.StringIO(txt_file)
 for items in (line.strip().split(),)}
```

And I don't know of a "better" way to split a list in two.

Comment: And though it's not really related to your primary question, I'd remark that `strip()` is redundant when you also `split()` (provided you don't pass arguments to `split()`).

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten that split also strips.

Comment: You're right about not needing the last `for`. I think it makes the code easier to read because I give the pieces names. I've never measured for a speed difference, though.

Comment: @Harvey Yeah, I doubt there's a significant performance difference. Personally, I find that 2 is usually my limit for nested `for` loops in comprehensions for readability, but it's certainly a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I've done as many as 6 or so, but if you format them clearly and use easy to read statements, they usually make perfect sense to the coder coming behind you.

Comment: I wish there was an "as" statement in comprehensions so that last line could be `with line.split() as items`. Maybe `using` as a new keyword instead of `with`.